# How do I set a cookie to expire/delete (axios react express)?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, axios

I am trying to set a cookie to expire after five seconds on logout, it works in postman but not in react when I try it. I can see that my access-token is now 'expiredtoken' and will expire in 5000ms in postman.

Here is my code,

Routers for login

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { username: username } });
    if(!user) res.status(400).json({error: `Username does not exist!`});

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((match) => {
        if(!match) res.status(400).json({error: 'Wrong password!'})

        const accessToken = createTokens(user);
        const options = {
            maxAge: 60*60*24*1000,
            secure: NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
            httpOnly: NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            path: '/',
        };

        res.cookie('access-token', accessToken, options);

        user.email = undefined;
        user.password = undefined;

        res.json({accessToken, user});
    })
});
```

logout

```
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        maxAge: 5000,
        secure: NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
        httpOnly: NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        path: '/',
    };

    res.cookie('access-token', 'expiredtoken', options)
    res.status(200).json({ status: 'logged out' });
})
```

logout in react

```
function Logout() {
    
    let history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        const config = { headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}, withCredentials: true};

        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/logout', config).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            history.push('/')
        })

    }, [history]);

    return (
        <div>
            logout page
        </div>
    )
}

export default Logout
```

Comment: Why should you wait for seconds to clear the cookie? Should be cleared immediately on logout.

Comment: just wanted to see (could actually use clearCookie to remove it on logout), although my main problem is that it isn't reflecting on react.

Answer (score 0):

this is what solved it for me,

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/logout', {},{withCredentials: true})
```

adding that empty object before withCredentials.

Comment: What this empty object actually do?

Comment: @JothiKannan 2nd prop is for payload, third is for parameters.